# How to upscale only few points of an image, Image processing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, scaling, image-scaling

I am working on an problem wherein I downscale an image find interesting points in the downscaled image sort of like a Binary Image. Now I want to upscale only the interesting points (i.e the white pixel points) that I found in the downscaled image instead of upscaling the whole image and then finding the interesting points. What technique can be best used for this purpose.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to accomplish. What do you envision the result to look like? Only a few pixels upsampled? Do you mean finding the regions in the original image that correspond to the pixels in the downsampled image?

Comment: Regions in the original image corresponding to the pixels in the downsampled image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple relationship between the pixels in the downsampled image and those in the original image. For example, given an original image `O` that is downsampled by a factor 4 in each dimension, yielding a downsamapled image `D`, then a pixel `(i,j)` in `D` corresponds to a set of 4x4 pixels in `O` with the top-left pixel being `(i*4,j*4)` and the bottom-right pixel being `(i*4+3j*4+3)`.

Thus, after detecting a set of pixels in `D`, you can find the 4x4 patches corresponding to those pixels in `O`. There is no way of mapping your detection more precisely unless you are able to detect points in `D` with sub-pixel precision (e.g. by finding the location of a peak, which you can do by fitting a parabola or Gaussian to the peak).